# How to calculate objects within an array avoiding duplicates?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, count, duplicates

I have an array with event objects. In every objects I have a Child with childId and startDate and endDate. Think that I have the array of 100 events, but 28 of them has duplicates startDates. I would like to count events per day, not actually amount of all events.

```
List<Event> familysEvents = new ArrayList<Event>();
    // List of children
    Map<String,ActualChrChild> children = new HashMap<String,ActualChrChild>();

    for (Child child : response.getChildren()) {
        children.put(child.getId(),child);

    }


    for (RespEvent rEvent : response.getEvents()) {

    Event event = new Event();    

    event.setChildId(rEvent.getChildId());
    event.setFamilyId(rEvent.getFamilyId());
    event.setDate(rEvent.getStartTime().toLocalDate());
    ...
```

Now I have an array full of events and it is easy to get amount of all events with size(), but I would like to know events by specific dates. So if there is three events for same childId on the 17.10.2019 I would like to count it only once, not three times. So I would like to get amount of array for specific child without multiple events on the specific date. I would like to know how many events there is on that list so that if childID= 123 has three events on date 17.10.2019 it is calculated only once, not three times.

I think that this is possible but it goes over my head, something about cloned arrays maybe and removing from another. Thanks for helping!

Comment: what is the relation between `Event` and `Child`?

Comment: `Event`? `java.awt.Event`?

Comment: In every event there is childID so they are connected event.setChildId(rEvent.getChildId()); Event is my own object type, not javas Event.

Comment: Alright, then please post the code for the following custom object types: `Event`, `RespEvent` `ActualChrChild`, and `Child`.

Comment: Also, what are you trying to find? I can't understand what you're trying to ask.

Comment: I would like to know how many events there is on that list so that if childID= 123 has three events on date 17.10.2019 it is calculated only once, not three times.